# How to improve speed of input command in android?

Tags: java, android, command

I am working on a project which aim to assist the disabled to use their android device better (Mostly for education purpose). We came up with some idea about alternative input device, and using input command to replay that on screen. At the moment, we have to root the phone and using input command

```
input tab x y
```

But it took about 3 seconds to perform a single tab which is too slow.
After dug deep into documents, i came across `sendevent.c` and i realize that it open and close interface file for each command. Is there anyway that i can write input directly to that file which may improve delay for each single tab?

Is there any anternative way to replay input? i know many app on appstore that can perform tab very quickly without root as well.

Thank you very much

Edit: This is the block of code i am using:

```
int i = 0;
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        while (true){
            try {
                Process process = null;
                process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su", null, null);
                DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
                String cmd = "/system/bin/input tap " + 273 + " " + (232+90) + "\n"; //760 116
                os.writeBytes(cmd);
                os.writeBytes("exit\n");
                os.flush();
                os.close();
                process.waitFor();
            } catch(Exception e) {
                Log.i("CommandSU", e.toString());
                i--;
            }
            i++;
            if (i >= 1){
                break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

So I actually did this for some keyboards.  What we did was recorded events as they were happening in a log file.  Then we wrote code that replayed that file by creating a thread, then reading it in and making direct touch/keyboard/other events in the same order at the same timing, sleeping until it needs to create the next command.  That worked fairly well, but debugging was slow.

Then we rewrote all our algorithms to work on streams of inputs with times embedded in the input.  We could then fake out any set of inputs we wanted.  That worked blazingly fast for debugging, and became our goto method.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer. At first we thought that the delay was between each key pressed in our aternative input device, but turn out it wasnt the case, the reason was because of how `input tab x y` work, i see some people changed the code in `sendevent.c` so that it only close the stream when finish replay. About your project, can i get more detail about how you simulate tab on screen?

Comment: In our case we made an actual software keyboard, so we had direct access.  You're never going to get any real speed out of needing to invoke a process like that.  If becoming the keyboard isn't an option, I'd be looking into incorporating the input app into your app, and just doing what the input app does.  Otherwise you're talking about launching a process and multiple IPCs per invocation.

Comment: Yes iam looking for document on this problem, or maybe some example